# Sum of products of positive integers and non-negative reals, the latter of which has the sum of at most 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing

Suppose we have two positive integers $a_1$ and $a_2$. Then, we have two non-negative reals $b_1$ and $b_2$ so that:

$$b_1+b_2\leq1$$

Then, suppose we have a value $c$ so that:

$$c=a_1*b_1+a_2*b_2$$

Is it possible to prove that the value of $c$ can never have a value greater than $max(a_1, a_2)$ (i.e. the greater one out of $a_1$ and $a_2$)?

Comment: Yes, it is a very simple proof.

Comment: Worst case scenario, $b_1+b_2=1$ and what you have is an affine combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$ with non-negative coefficients, therefore it lies in the convex hull of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 \le \max(a_1,a_2) b_1 + \max(a_1,a_2) b_2$